# How and where in VS2008 I can see my Linq commands being translate into Transact-SQL statements?

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2008-sp1

Linq commands are translated into transact-sql statements. I've VS2008 professional. How and where can I see how this majic happens? (by debugging?)

**EDIT**

Let's say I have this

```
var allProducts = db.Products;
```

I guess this will be translate by

```
SELECT * FROM Products
```

Where can I look at to see that? For instance, when I debug my code, I can see on the bottom are changing value each time I press f10. Is there something like that in vs2008 for linq command?

Comment: You can also use a profiler, e.g. http://www.huagati.com/L2SProfiler/ (if you're interested in more than just the SQL, that is... if just the SQL, go for the Log property as suggested by Janus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) property on the DataContext object.

Comment: I'm not sure if Richard77 intends to see how the SQL generation works or if he wants to log the generated SQL.

Comment: Myself, I agree that I didn't state clearly my thoughts. So, see the edit above. The idea is to show to my friend that all linq does is translating linq commands into transact-sql. He keeps writing raw transact-sql (which is not bad but he needs to know the alternatives too)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure VS to step into .NET source code:

[Configuring Visual Studio to Debug .NET Framework Source Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sburke/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code?wa=wsignin1.0)